# How to use ng-grid (from AngularUI) with two-dimensional array data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I'd really like to use the AngularUI ng-grid module for my project, however all the examples show the grid data as an array of objects, where as my server-side endpoint returns an array of arrays like this:

```
[[1842860, 1.8691, 5.2067], [2235242, 0.7141, 2.0789], [2235240, 1.2816, 3.8265]]
```

Attempting to use ng-grid w/ two-dimensional array data as given above doesn't work. How can I use ng-grid with data of this nature without having to transform it?

Thanks!

Comment: Errm? Just like that? http://plnkr.co/edit/qACOck?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok, the problem was I was using AngularJS 1.3 which, when presented with a matrix of data as I indicated above, would barf on rendering the cells.

Using AngularJS 1.2.x solved the problem.